# Visual Studio debugging program locked in memory

Tags: visual-studio-2010, debugging

When i am debugging my program and an error occur, the debug session ends, but the program remains in memory. Using the activity manager of Windows to close it does not work. I need to close Visual Studio in order to kill the process. 
Why is this happening?

Comment: Are you talking about the "some-executable.vshost.exe" thing? In that case it isn't all that strange. Also, does the error occurs in your code or in an external lib (like, code you can't easily debug yourself, you'll only get the disassembly)?

Comment: The error(s) occurs in my code, that is, when i am debugging and i cross a line of my code that does something wrong, the debugging session ends but the program remain in memory. I don't know what the *vshost.exe you are referring to is.

Comment: Hmm does the debugging session really "end" or does it just pause? I'd expect the latter to be the case. You can see if the program is paused by the "playback" type buttons in the tool bar. Alternatively, you should get some hints by opening the Debug menu...

Answer (score 0):

When during debugging a program error occurs, the program usually does not "end". Instead, the debugger (VS2010) pauses execution, allowing you to inspect the code resulting in the error. Depending on the language used (e.g. C#) and the way you compiled your program, you may even be able to edit the program on the fly, move the execution cursor back a bit and continue the program from there.

If the Debug toolbar is visible (in my case it shows up automatically whenever I'm debugging), you should see a couple of "playback" buttons, allowing you to start/continue, pause, stop your program etc. If you stop your program, it will be gone from the task manager too.

As I mentioned in a comment on your question, you can also use the Debug menu to accomplish these tasks.